# Post method not working, only get request

Tags: python, django, html-table, csrf, delete-row

I have a form like this:

```
<form method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <div class="mb-3">
     <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="url" name="delete-id" value="{{ url.id }}">
 </div>
 <div class="mb-3">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Delete</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

This form is embedded in a cell of a table.
I make a post request in the form but when I'm testing the request.method, it always gives me the GET answer.

```
if request.method == 'post':
    Url.objects.get(id=request.POST.get['delete-id']).delete()
```

Here request.method is always GET and I don't understand why.

Here is my entire function:

```
@login_required
def website(request, website_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        Url.objects.get(id=request.GET['delete-id']).delete()

    customer_id = request.session.get('customer_id')
    context = {
        'website': Website.objects.get(id=website_id, customer__id=customer_id)
    }
    return render(request, 'main/website.html', context)
```

Comment: Are you getting request.method as GET even after submitting the form?

Comment: yes, I'm getting GET even after pressing the delete button

Comment: if you get it as `GET` then you have something wrong with `<form method="post">` - maybe you have only `<form>` without `method` - use `Ctr+U` in web browser to see source code of page. Maybe you generate page using wrong template.

Comment: if it's possible add more from your views and template fie

Comment: The page source is not updated. I'm running on docker container. The method is delete in page source. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: so you have wrong files in container and you have to update them in container. And sometimes `flask` need also to restart to load new HTML from templates.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `if request.method == 'post':` by `if request.method == 'POST':`. As it is, it will never be `post` as it's case-sensitive.

Comment: Even if i check in this way, when I' debugging the method is still GET..

Comment: I tried your code and I get a post method, are you sure you don't redirect before or something like that ?

Comment: This sounds good to me, I don't see why you're getting a GET method here

Comment: I posted the entire function ... I'm not using any redirect on it